# Sanitizer deletes data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on `nodejs` project which uses `MongoDB`. Lately, I implemented [mongoose-sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sanitizer)
 to all my Schemas and I noticed that sometimes it deletes data from DB. I know it should not allow inserting 'potentially harmful' data but it didn't seem that something was wrong with them. It deletes even boolean type fields. I don't know where should I start looking because it seemed that the usage of that library is really simple.

My code:

```
const sanitizerPlugin = require('mongoose-sanitizer');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({...})

userSchema.plugin(sanitizerPlugin);
```

Comment: Can you add a reproduce case here in the question?

Comment: Do you mean what data it deletes?

Comment: No the schema and sample code so that I can investigate it and also I saw the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sanitizer which uses https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer, author of this caja htnl sanitizer says https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer#caveats so I would suggest to try some alternatives.

Comment: The problem is that it happens randomly, but I would love to use alternative if there is one. Do you know about any?